# What is the shutdown reason of my system?

Tags: boot, shutdown, reboot, system, info

I need to check how long my system was up and what was the reason of shutdown
For example if somebody did that i need time and username of that person and if it was because of plug out i want to know that too.
Can something like that happen?
How we can separate shutdown by user and by plug out?

Comment: Shutdowns that are directed by users are logged. Unexpected poweroffs, regardless of the many possible causes, are not logged. Are you asking how to read your logs? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: After the system comes up again, the terminal command `sudo journalctl   b -1 -ex` will show the system logs leading up to the crash/shutdown. You can look at other shutdowns by varying the `-b -1` option. If nothing stands out, suspect overheating or sudden power outage. Do `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`, read `man journalctl`.

Comment: The `last` command might give you clues about how long the system was up before it rebooted, but it doesn't log shutdowns, not even clean ones.

Comment: all I want is to find out if specific shutdown is unexpected or by users.